# Remove vertical tabulation (vt) in query in Redshift

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, amazon-redshift

Is there a way to remove vertical tabulation directly in query in Amazon Redshift using Replace, Translate or Regexp? I'm having problems with this [VT] and I don't want to use sed to remove this characters.

Thansk!

Comment: I found the solution:

translate(description,chr(11),'')

chr(11) = vertical tab

Comment: you should add this as an answer, so that someone else facing the same issue can quickly see the solution.

Comment: Done, @ketan. Posted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!

translate(description,chr(11),'')

Because chr(11) = vertical tab.

Comment: consider adding more details so that someone coming to this answer in future can understand how the problem was actually fixed.